# Erlang conversion for one format to another format

Tags: erlang

How to convert this string format `"{hari, localost}"` into this: `{"hari", "localost"}`, in Erlang?

I tried to convert this format with lot of trial and error method, but I can't get the solution.

Comment: What about `list_to_tuple(string:tokens("{hari, localost}", "{, }")).`?

Comment: Well, yes, but it's very error-prone. I'd suggest checking `erl_scan:string` (have no means to do that here at work) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to convert from string, so you can use the modules erl_scan and erl_parse:

```
1> erl_scan:string("{hari, localost}"++".").
{ok,[{'{',1},
     {atom,1,hari},
     {',',1},
     {atom,1,localost},
     {'}',1},
     {dot,1}],
    1}
2> {ok,Term} = erl_parse:parse_term(Tokens).             
{ok,{hari,localost}}
3>Conv = fun({X, Y}) -> {atom_to_list(X), atom_to_list(Y)} end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
4> Conv(Term).
{"hari","localost"}
5>
```

**Note 1** the function erl_parse:parse_term/1 will work only if Terms is a valid expression, it is why I had to add a "." at the end of the input.

**Note 2** yo can directly transform to the final expression if you quote the terms in the input expression:

```
1> {ok,Tokens,_} = erl_scan:string("{\"hari\", \"localost\"}.").     
{ok,[{'{',1},
     {string,1,"hari"},
     {',',1},
     {string,1,"localost"},
     {'}',1},
     {dot,1}],
    1}
2> {ok,Term} = erl_parse:parse_term(Tokens).                        
{ok,{"hari","localost"}}
3>
```