# Convert bitstring to tuple

Tags: binary, erlang

I'm trying to find out how to convert an Erlang bitstring to a tuple, but so far without any luck.

What I want is to get from for example `<<"{1,2}">>` the tuple `{1,2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modules `erl_scan` and `erl_parse`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552487/113848). Since `erl_scan:string` requires a string, not a binary, you have to convert the value with `binary_to_list` first:

```
> {ok, Scanned, _} = erl_scan:string(binary_to_list(<<"{1,2}">>)).
{ok,[{'{',1},{integer,1,1},{',',1},{integer,1,2},{'}',1}],1}
```

Then, you'd use `erl_parse:parse_term` to get the actual term.  However, this function expects the term to end with a dot, so we have to add it explicitly:

```
> {ok, Parsed} = erl_parse:parse_term(Scanned ++ [{dot,0}]).
{ok,{1,2}}
```

Now the variable `Parsed` contains the result:

```
> Parsed.
{1,2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary functions and erlang:list_to_tuple/1

```
1> B = <<"{1,2}">>.
<<"{1,2}">>
2> list_to_tuple([list_to_integer(binary_to_list(X)) || X <- binary:split(binary:part(B, 1, byte_size(B)-2), <<",">>, [global])]).
{1,2}
```